# GNU inline asm: which registers get clobbered by __stdcall?

Tags: c++, gcc, x86, inline-assembly, stdcall

If I am using the `call` instruction, via GNU's inline assembler in C++ code, to call a function I know uses the `__stdcall` convention, do I have to list any registers as clobbered?

I'm not finding great guidance on the internet, but it looks like `%eax`, `%edx`, and `%ecx` are caller-save, with the former two being reserved for the return value.

Here's my code. I want to know what I need to put after the third colon.

```
#include <cstdint>

namespace {

inline uint64_t invoke_stdcall(uint64_t (* stdcall_func)())
{
    unsigned long hi32, lo32;
    asm(
        "call %2"
        : "=d" (hi32), "=a" (lo32)
        : "m" (stdcall_func)
        : /* HELP! What goes here? */
    );
    return static_cast<uint64_t>(hi32) << 32 | static_cast<uint32_t>(lo32);
}

} // anonymous namespace
```

[This message thread](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2011-01/msg00079.html) is the best I can find on the internet, but I haven't been able to find anything that says "this is what `__stdcall` assumes it can modify without saving"...

Comment: Each platform has different constraints (eg. Windows and Linux won't have the same requirements, not to mention 32 vs 64 bits). The best resource I ever found is [Agner Fog's C++ calling conventions](http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf), which will give you the information you want and much more.

Comment: Wikipedia is pretty good too: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

Comment: Thx both. @Mats, for whatever reason "designated for use within the function" in the Wiki wasn't explicit enough for me, but that must be what they're saying.

Comment: @syam, that manual is awesome. Looks like Chapter 6 sums it up.

Comment: As I've documented in the answer below, MS has pretty decent documentation for this.

Comment: the way you do this all you can invoke are functions that are _not_ taking arguments. What exactly is the reason for doing this, instead of using function attributes ?

Comment: @FrankH., I simplified for the purposes of illustration by removing the argument pushing code. This is a chunk of the marshalling glue which has to be able to invoke `__stdcall` functions from a different language environment. For the purposes of this question, all I needed to know was about register clobbering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MS does explain that EAX, EDX and ECX are "destroyed" by calls, all other registers must be preserved by callee in 32-bit code, [link to MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/argument-passing-and-naming-conventions) - it doesn't matter which calling convention is used.

So, to be clear, you need to mark `ecx` as clobbered, since `eax` and `edx` are already being used in your inline assembler.

And for x86-64, the documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention#callercallee-saved-registers), and says

> The registers RBX, RBP, RDI, RSI, R12, R13, R14, and R15 are considered nonvolatile and must be saved and restored by a function that uses them.

Comment: You also need to declare all of ST0..7, MM0..7, and XMM0..7 as clobbered (in 32-bit mode), and k0..7 if AVX-512.  In 64-bit mode, also xmm8..15 (or xmm0..31 and k0..7 `#ifdef __AVX512F__`).  See [Calling printf in extended inline ASM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37502841)  .  If this is Windows, XMM6..15 are call-preserved, but YMM6..15 aren't and there's no way to tell GCC that only the upper 16 bytes can get wiped out.  Perhaps `#ifdef __AVX__` around the xmm6..15 clobbers, since if this function's asm isn't using AVX, it won't care about YMM uppers.